#  How to implement different color schemes in your themes

Tags: css

This question is for theme developers.

I know how to use the settings API to gather input data, but I was wondering what's the best way include the styles.

Let's say you have 4-5 versions of the design, each with its own CSS rules and images. Options:

1. You stuff all the CSS in style.css and trigger the color change trough a body class. In this case you get the browser to load CSS rules and images that are not used (eg. selected option: "red", and you have rules for "blue", "green" as well).
2. Create separate stylesheets for each variant, and enqueue the selected style in the page. This could make the theme hard to maintain, because if you change one CSS file, you need to revise all the others too.
3. Create separate stylesheets for each variant, but only with the extra color styles. So you enqueue a big "common.css" file and the CSS for the selected color scheme (which is small). Here you make an extra HTTP request :P
4. ?

Comment: Wouldn't option 1 be just as much to maintain as option 2?  Wouldn't `common.css` be included in the theme's `style.css`?  If I were doing it, I would put all the common css in the theme's `style.css` (that's what it's for, right?), and create separate stylesheets for the color options.  If you wanted to separate `common.css` from `style.css` you could `@import common.css` from the color option's sheet instead of enqueuing it separately.

Answer (score 3):

I would put all the common css in the theme's `style.css`, and create separate stylesheets for the color options.

I would also put color options in their own folder with the images for that style.  This way you can keep the filenames the same between color options to make maintaining the code a little easier.

If you wanted to separate `common.css` from `style.css` you could `@import common.css` from the color option's sheet instead of enqueuing it separately.

Comment: This is **exactly** what I do. Using a consistent naming scheme for `{color}.css` and all the related `{color}-foo.png` (etc.) images makes conditional enqueues especially simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for that! Define a global stylesheet and one for each color. Set variables for color codes in the color sheets and use them in the global sheet, then @import the global stylesheet into each of the color stylesheets.

Example:

global.less

```
body{
    background: @bgColor;
}
```

red.less

```
@bgColor: red;

@import "global.less";
```

That gives you one standalone stylesheet per color, so you can go for option 2 but still maintain only one stylesheet! All of the advantages of all options combined, without any of the disadvantages :)

Comment: well, it does have the disadvantage of requiring another http request to load the less js file, and js obviously has to be enabled for it to work.

Comment: You can compile the LESS file and include the CSS only. Dead easy with http://incident57.com/less/

Comment: Keep in mind that using default CSS `@import` [is not recommended](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#AvoidCssImport)!
You'd be better off just doing the second HTTP request. Using @import with LESS will merge the files on compilation.

Comment: if you pre-compile the css file it defeats the entire purpose of using less in this instance.

Comment: Don't really get why. The goal is to minimize maintainence, CSS rendering time and HTTP load. With my solution you have to maintain all the styles only once, the browser doesn't have to process a single unused line of CSS and you can put everything in to one single stylesheet (per color).

Comment: how exactly is it allowing the user to select the color scheme at runtime?

Comment: As I said, option 2: Enqueue the stylesheet for the selected color. If the user selects 'red' as a color scheme, you load red.css, which is compiled out of global.less and red.less.

Comment: oh I see, sorry misunderstood. the user isn't selecting their own color, just one of the few precompiled ones.